# Setting up a click listener on an item populated by a database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, onclick

I am just in my third month since I officially started learning to code, it has been an interesting ride.
Currently, I am trying to create a simple sales management android application using android studio out of a simple database sample code I got.
I am stuck at setting up the right java code to enable the following:

- a user chooses a product to buy by clicking a Check Box (@+id/choice)
- he enters the quantity of products to buy example 5 (@+id/quantity)
- the application is supposed to multiply the price of the product (@+id/price) and the quantity and display the total (@+id/total).

The format for the individual items is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Soda" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="1000/=" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="*" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="amount"
        android:inputType="number" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="=" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="total" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(i have deleted some polishing codes so as to shorten that code and still show the most important parts).
The name and price of the product is populated by a SQLite Database that is created using the usual java files like the Contract, the Dbhelper, the Provider and the Cursor Adapter.
The user will enter the products name and price in another activity and all the products even more than 50 products, will be populated using that format on the following listview layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SalesActivity2">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sales_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So far, everything else works fine. The user can enter as many products as he chooses. The database is able to populate the products on the listview as per the format and the layout.
The challenge is in setting up the right java code in the SalesActivity2 to enable those calculations and show the total amount.
I know setting up click listeners will be required but I am not sure on the right way to set them up as the user will need to click on more than one place ie the button and while setting up the quantity of products to buy.
I have spent the last five days looking for the answer but in all answers i got, there was something missing causing the application to have errors or to not do anything.
I am looking forward to your suggestion on how to best solve that challenge.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener to your edittext which takes product quantity from the user.By default it should be blank or disabled,when user choose that product its text should be changed to 1(as per my logic) and if user itself make changes the value in it, then calculate the total amount.

Now to get that event you add TextWatcher on your EditText

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

whenever user changes text you can calculate the updated total amount.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add `OnCheckedChangeListener` to your `CheckBox`, to show `total` price for single `quantity` when user first `click` on `Checkbox` and to clear `quantity` & `total` price when user `un-check` the `CheckBox`.

**2.** Add `TextChangedListener` to `EditText`, to show total price when user start typing `quantity`.

**Try this:**

```
    CheckBox checkBoxChoice = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.choice);
    final EditText editQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    final TextView textPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
    final TextView textTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);


    checkBoxChoice.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
            if (checked) { // Required to show total price for single quantity when user click on checkbox
                int quantity = 1;
                int price = Integer.parseInt(textPrice.getText().toString());
                int total = price * quantity;
                textTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            } else { // Required to clear quantity and total price when user un-check checkbox
                editQuantity.setText("0");
                textTotal.setText("0");
            }
        }
    });

    // Required to show total price when user start typing quantity
    editQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
            int price = Integer.parseInt(textPrice.getText().toString());
            int total = price * quantity;

            textTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

**FYI,** on your `price` TextView, try setting only price value(`1000`) instead of string(`1000/=`), as we are getting price from `price` TextView.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Yes of course, it is the user who enters the price, that value is just a place holder, let me try this, thanks

Comment: This seems like it will work but we will have to deal with the Null Pointer Exception it throws at "checkBoxChoice.setOnCheckedChangeListener...". Somehow the app is not able to locate the exact position of the checkbox on the view. From my research so far, i tried wrapping that code around an on item click listener tied to the list view. I ended up with that situation whereby there are no errors but the app does nothing after i click on the total text view.

Comment: There is something that we are still missing here to make it work. The name of the main listview layout is "activity_sales2" and the name of the layout for the individual items is "sales_list2". I hope they will help in setting up the right code to get those view.

Comment: And the products are populated from a database onto that list view meaning there could be more than 50 products hence the requirement to set up a listener on a product on the right position in the listview with many products.